# How can I deploy function code to s3 with serverless since it is too large

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless

I got this error message with `sls deploy`

```
Error:
UPDATE_FAILED: HandlerLambdaFunction (AWS::Lambda::Function)
Resource handler returned message: "Unzipped size must be smaller than 262144000 bytes
```

Usually, I will use `--use-s3-bucket` with claudiajs to handle large code base. I just started to use `serverless` framework, so I am interested in having a solution for that.

Answer (score 1):

There is 2 types of AWS Lambda deployment:

- zip archive (artifacts pulled from s3 bucket)
- container image (pulled from aws ecr in most cases)

Zip archive approach has a hard limit of 50MB zipped, and 250 MB unzipped for the deployment package. Deployment package includes any zipped code and associated layers if applies.

One way to solve the issue is using packaging tools, like webpack or similar, to minify/compress your deployment package, these tools in a lot of cases allow to significantly decrease the size of your build.

The downside of using additional packaging tools is that you have to add extra steps to you build process and configure these tools to meet your requirements which in some cases might not be super straight forward.

The container image deployment type has a limit of 10GB so you can package a lot more stuff into your build including 3rd party binaries etc. But that way you will have to add Docker setup into your project, if it is not already there.

One of the benefits is that with Docker image you can debug your function locally using the same environment as AWS Lambda.

There is a lot of docs/tutorial on how to deploy lambda as a container image provided by AWS and others. I'd start [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html)